# Swift 3: How to mute / unmute microphone during video recording using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am recording video, creating a custom camera using AVFoundation and Swift 3. Now I want to add functionality to mute/unmute audio during video recording on button click. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you were using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to record your video from `AVFoundation`

There is no direct way of doing it but if you dig through the documentation you can see

- `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` is a subclass of `AVCaptureOutput`
- You can get audio connection alone from your `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` via `func connection(withMediaType mediaType: String!) -> AVCaptureConnection!`
   by passing media type as audio
- Once you get the auido connection alone, just disable it

#### Example in swift

```
let movieFileOutput : AVCaptureMovieFileOutput
// your code to initialize output
var audioConnection :AVCaptureConnection? = movieFileOutput.connection(withMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio)
if let connection = audioConnection {
    connection.isEnabled = false;
}
```

#### Form documentation

for `AVCaptureConnection` property `enabled`

> The value of this property is a BOOL that determines whether the receiver's output should consume data 
>           from its connected inputPorts when a session is running. Clients can set this property to stop the 
>           flow of data to a given output during capture.  The default value is YES.